# Can anyone give an InAppBrowser sample app for the Ionic 2 framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Can anyone give an `InAppBrowser` sample app? I am new to Ionic 2 and I just can't get it running.

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {

  constructor() {
 }

openBrowser(){
let browser = new InAppBrowser('https://ionic.io', '_system');
}

}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Hello Ionic</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="content">
<button (click)="openBrowser()">Open Browser</button>

</ion-content>
```

This throws the following error:

```
TypeScript error: C:/Users/Chirag Jagga/IonicFinal/app/pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic.ts(14,15): Error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

taken from : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/

Comment: We aren't here to find starter projects for you. Maybe try GitHub or the project's own website.

Comment: I tried few projects on github and on their site too.
Most of them are based on old versions of the framework

Comment: Well, maybe you'll have to do better than *"just can't get it running"*; give a [mcve]. If you can't get the ones you've already found working, what's the point of giving you another?

Comment: I have added the code and the error please check if you can help. :)

Comment: What version of ionic, ionic-native and cordova-plugin-inappbrowser are you using?

Comment: ionic 2 latest beta version 
can you tell where I can check ionic-native version 
added the plugin using the CLI $ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 
Repo: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Comment: You can find your version of ionic-native inside your package.json. I'm not sure if the most recent ionic-native (2.0.3) is supported in ionic beta.11, so you should probably install ionic-native 1.3.21 using `npm i --save ionic-native@1.3.21`

Comment: "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.10",
I am on 1.3.10 as per the package.json file so I don't think that would be an issue

Comment: @bvx89 i just checked the package.json file and it doesn't show the inAppBrowser plugin in the list I tried importing it again but there was no error message or any message 
C:\Users\Chirag Jagga\IonicFinal>ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

C:\Users\Chirag Jagga\IonicFinal> 

Any other way to add the plugin?

Just checked in config.xml in visual studio it shows the plugin as installed

Comment: You can potentally still have another version of ionic-native inside your node_modules folder, so you could try to check the package.json in the node_modules/ionic-native folder. The error is only a typescript error, so there is a definition file that's wrong.

As for the plugin, you should have a config.xml inside the root of your project which shows all your plugins for your app. There's also a plugins folder where you can check each plugin's package.json to see if it's the correct version.

Comment: One solution is to not care about the typescript error, and try to use cordova directly. [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#example-1)

Comment: Thanks for the link will give it a try .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser'


@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: 'templateUrl: 'build/pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic.html'})


export class HelloIonicPage {

  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }


openBrowser(){
  const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionic.io', '_system' );
   browser.close();
 }
}
```

Make sure you add 'InAppBrowser' as a provider in your's apps module provoders:

```
import { InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser'


@NgModule({
  . . .
  . . .
providers: [..,InAppBrowser,...]
})
```

check it out here: https://matthiasomisore.com/index.php/2017/06/01/ionic2-using-inappbrowser-to-load-a-web-browser/